# calculate the sum from json array and storing it in json object at different reference in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Situation**

I have `firebase` database that looks like this:

[image]

But i want to add a balance `json` object and calculate the sum of amount on every write to the database.

And it should look something like this:

[image]

Now, i am using `firebase` cloud functions for this purpose. I want to read `txn.amount` from `"/Txns/{Id}"` and do `balance=balance+txn.amount` on every write operation in the database.

This is my `index.js` file from `firebase` cloud functions

```
exports.addToBalance = functions.database.ref('/Txns/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const rootRef = event.ref.root
        var currentBalance // variable to store the current balance got from promise
        const txn = event.data.val() // getting the data from onwrite 
        console.log("got the balance reference :" + balanceRef)

        rootRef.balance = 0.00 // set balance to zero
        const setBalanceZeroPromise = ...... ? // how to get reference to balance & set the value to 0 
        return setBalanceZeroPromise.then(event => {
            console.log("balance set to zero")
        })
    })
```

Please help !

Comment: Supply full code please.

Comment: I am getting objects `onWrite` on `/Txns/{pushId}` but i want to write sum of object on {/balance} after reading the value from `onWrite` function. I don't know how to proceed that's why i haven't written any code.@JohnKennedy

Comment: Kindly show all code leading to the one above.

Comment: do you need me to supply android java code for the app? because i have already provided index.js code.

Comment: Are those all the code in your `index.js` file?

Comment: ya..  i want to know how can i achieve the desired result described here..@johnkennedy